# How to directly visit JSP pages with Spring loaded?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'd like to know how to directly visit JSP pages under some directory of `WEB-INF` with Spring running on `/` path without writing any controller for view forwarding.

For example, I have a project `myapp` structured as follows:

```
src
WebRoot
`-- WEB-INF
    |-- public
    |   `-- example.jsp
    |-- views
```

Now, I want to visit `example.jsp` by directly navigating to `http://localhost/myapp/public/example` without implementing any controller.

What I've tried so far:

1. added `<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/WEB-INF/public/"/>` to my context xml, but it just won't work, the container keeps complaining about `HTTP 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND /public/example.jsp`.
2. added an internal resource view resolver to my context xml.

   ```
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix">
           <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
       </property>
       <property name="suffix">
           <value>.jsp</value>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ```

   but I'm not sure what to do next, I maybe put many JSP pages under `/WEB-INF/public`, so writing a controller for each of them will be tedious.

Is there any canonical way to do this? please help!

Comment: you want to do something like this: http://localhost:8080/myapp/home am i right?

Comment: @T.Jung  the question is updated.

Comment: You should not even try that. If you need to directly access a JSP you should store it outside WEB-INF. A JSP is not a **static** ressource. It it compiled into a servlet by the servlet container, and that compiled code is called by the servlet container.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You're making a good point, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring mvc we have one option 
`<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="example"/>`.

This redirects the example.jsp page when you type / in the browser

Comment: It solved my problem, nevertheless, the view-name should be `public/example`

Comment: @JerryChin: the `<mvc:view-controller .../>` line does declare a controller to server the view...

Comment: @SergeBallesta but in my case, it's the simplest way to solve the question. don't you think so?

Comment: @JerryChin: Of course it is, and it is the SpringMVC way! I had misunderstood your requirements and thought you actually wanted to directly serve the JSP with no controller at all. Here one exists but it is fully provided by Spring so you do not have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that in your dispatcher servlet:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Where the jsp folder contains your jsp files. From controller you can directly use the jsp name. You don't need to mention the jsp folder going by the above definition.

Comment: I want to visit the JSP page **directly from the browser** with no controller implemented, will the above be going to work?

Comment: You have tagged spring mvc, where the 'c' stands for controller... you should use controller for your request mappings and to load jsps

Comment: What if there's just a self-contained JSP page, and I want the user visiting it directly, just as the way how the static resources are accessed, how do I do?